# Fetch results undefined on first call

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vue-component, nuxt.js

I have the following Vue methods. When clicking on the edit button, `onEditUserPermissions` is called.  That function also fetches `this.fetchUserPermissions`.  The request does finish, and a response is received.

```
methods:{
  onEditUserPermissions(item){
    this.userCheckbox = true
    let user = item.id
    this.selectedUser = item.id;
    
    this.fetchUserPermissions(user)
    for (let x of this.assignedUserPermissions){
      console.log('assigned',x.id)
      this.selectedUserItems.push(x.id)
    }
    
    this.editedIndex =  'users'
    this.dialog = true
  },
  fetchUserPermissions(user){
    this.$axios.get('/permissions/assigned/user/'+user)
    .then(res => {
      this.assignedUserPermissions = res.data
    })
  },
}
```

When I first click, the `for of` loop doesnt work, it doesnt iterate, however, when clicked again, it works.  I may be too close to the project but can anyone tell why?

Comment: Please share more details - did you ensure that the request to the backend is finished before iterating over that array?

Comment: @NicoHaase ok, I edited my question, but yes, the request finishes and a response is received.

Comment: My question was: how did you ensure that the request finishes **before** you iterate over that array? Axios is a promise-based client, so the method `fetchUserPermissions` does not wait for the response

Comment: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321) and [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for the http promise to resolve before attempting to access the data.  It works the second time because then it uses the result from the first fetch.

First, you need to return the promise from `fetchUserPermissions`, and then you need to wait for that promise in `onEditUserPermissions`:

```js
methods: {
  async onEditUserPermissions(item){         // `async` keyword
    this.userCheckbox = true
    let user = item.id
    this.selectedUser = item.id;
    
    await this.fetchUserPermissions(user);   // awaiting the promise

    for (let x of this.assignedUserPermissions){
      console.log('assigned',x.id)
      this.selectedUserItems.push(x.id)
    }
    
    this.editedIndex = 'users';
    this.dialog = true    
  }

  fetchUserPermissions(user){
    return this.$axios.get('/permissions/assigned/user/'+user)  // return the promise
    .then(res => {
      this.assignedUserPermissions = res.data
    })
  },
}
```